# Magento Make Coupon Field in Cart only visible on Click

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, shopping-cart, phtml

For conversion purposes I'm trying to hide the coupon field in the magento cart and only make it visible upon a click. This is adviced by all conversion experts, so it's weird Magento hasn't adopted it yet. But then again, there are a lot of things weird about Magento :-p.

I've found this:
[Magento hide / show coupon field in cart page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/22456/magento-hide-show-coupon-field-in-cart-page/22465#22465) on stack exchange with a suggestion. But I'm going to need a little more help.

I tried the solution, but it doesn't work with magento 1.9.2.3. Also the topic is over a year old. I'm not very familiar with javascript, so a detaild instruction would be very helpfull.

I hope there's someone who also thinks this is a good idea and is able to help me achieve this. I'm sure there are a lot of people who want the exact same thing, but don't know how.

All help is very much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Feike

Answer (score 0):

I made some alterations to the answer: [Magento hide / show coupon field in cart page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/22456/magento-hide-show-coupon-field-in-cart-page/22465#22465)

Now it works for me. The code for the coupon.phtml was slightly different between magento 1.7 and 1.9. I updated this and now the answer from the other post is working for me.